# Excel vba create a hyperlink

Tags: vba, hyperlink, excel-2010

I'm trying to create a hyperlink with vba.  I have a macro that extracts a report name (string) and report ID (string) from a website.  These 2 pieces of info are written to the 'Results' sheet in Excel.  So far, so good.

The next step is to create a hyperlink in the 3rd column that appears to be the Report Name.  However, the URL for the hyperlink is https://PeopleSoft/psreports/prd/ and the Report ID.  It would look like this:
https://PeopleSoft/psreports/prd/123456.

I can put the URL together.  However, what I'm trying to do is create a hyperlink in the 3rd column and looks like the report name in the first column.

I'm having trouble getting the report name and URL together to create the hyperlink.  Is this possible?  Any help would be greatly appreaciated.......

Comment: Can you show us the code that does not work?

Comment: @peakpeak.........the only code I had was to add a hyperlink but was struggling to add the report name.  The answer from braX below worked for me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to create a hyperlink on the active cell: (Use the *TextToDisplay* argument for the report name)

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    "https://peoplesoft/psreports/prd/", TextToDisplay:= _
    "Report Name"
```

Comment: decent answer, but you did not address the crux of the problem: *trouble getting the report name and URL together to create the hyperlink*

Comment: @braX..........thanks for the answer.......I was able to figure it out with the solution you provided.  Thanks for your help.......